# How to get command line arguments from position 1

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

Is there a way to get command line arguments in C# from `args[1]` and forward, excluding `args[0]`?

I've tried with this:

```
short argslenght = (short) args.Length;
string[] pargs = { "" };
for(int i = 1; i <= args.Length; i++)
{
    pargs[i-1] = args[i];
}
```

But gives me this error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Huh? You already got one, no? Very unclear!

Comment: `args.Skip(1)`? with `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: @TaW yes, I want to make the first argument (args[0]) to detect what function the program will do and then, it starts a process. I want that the second args and forward (args[1]...) to be the command line arguments for that new process.

Comment: You can feed them in in a for loop or go for linq as the others showed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are trying to read a value from the array of index which exceeds the limit of the array length. It is happening for the last value. If there are 5 arguments, you can read the last one by `args[4]` but in your loop, you are trying to read it by `args[5]` which is causing the error.

You need to use `Length -1` in your `For` loop, like this way:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= args.Length - 1; i++)
```

Or remove the `=` from the condition:

```
for(int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
```